# Facebook JS SDK returns XSS error and "user_denied" response without displaying Auth Popup on FB.Login

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a FB canvas app at http://apps.facebook.com/insideny/

Until very recently I was using an anchor link to send users to the OAUTH login flow.

Since I implemented the Facebook Javascript SDK I have used the following logic:

1) Initialize the FB API

```
    FB.init({
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    xfbml: true, 
    cookie: true,  
    oauth : true, 
    channelUrl: 'http://www.niteflymobile.com/insideny/channel.html' },
    {scope: 'email'});
```

2) Check for login status

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)    { ... } )
```

3) If the user is found to be loggedin (response.status == "connected") then set a proper cookie and redirect to logged in page.

4) **HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS** if response.status != "connected" (usually returns "not_authorized" for new user) then fire a call to FB.login(function(response)   { ... }).

4a) FB.login comes back with 2 errors of the following type:

"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL         static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3&error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.#cb=f22684144&origin=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.niteflymobile.com%2Ff185641ad8&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f39056acd8 from frame with URL www.niteflymobile.com/insideny/#. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

(http:// removed from both links to comply with SO rules for new users)

and in addition the object returned which I wrote to the console contains a null authResponse and status is "unknown" as opposed to the "not_authorized" it was just a moment ago.

The core problem here is that the popup for authorization is fired but is blank and quickly closes without any user interaction.

Any ideas/help/insight would be very much appreciated as I've been banging my head against this for quite a bit now and I suspect its a stupid mistake I just cant see because I'm in too deep.

I have just removed sandbox mode, could that have been a possible cause?

COMPLETE CODE BELOW:

```
     $('.fb_link').click(function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX', xfbml: true, cookie: true,  oauth : true, channelUrl: 'http://www.niteflymobile.com/insideny/channel.html' },{scope: 'email'});
                //setup fb login check
                 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)   {
                    if(response)    {
                        console.log(response);
                    if(response.status == "connected")  {

                            alert(response.status);
                            alert(response.authResponse.userID+"preajax");
                            //jquery cookie write
                            $.cookie('fbID', response.authResponse.userID, { expires: 29, path: '/' });
                            //secondary cookie write using only javascript
                            createCookie('fbID', response.authResponse.userID, 29);
                            //bandaid to fire ajax to set cookie on server side if the js side fails
                            var fbID_check = readCookie('fbID');
                            if(fbID_check)  {
                                alert("fbID cookie set "+fbID_check);
                                window.location = "http://apps.facebook.com/insideny/";
                            }
                            else    {
                                url_vars = "fbID="+response.authResponse.userID;
                                $.ajax({ 
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "set_fb_cookie.php",
                                    data: url_vars,  
                                    success: function(data){

                                        alert(data + "passed back from ajax");
                                        var fbID_check_2 = readCookie("fbID");
                                        alert(fbID_check_2 + "read from cookie");
                                        window.location = "http://apps.facebook.com/insideny/";
                                    }

                                });
                                return false;
                            }

                            alert(response.authResponse.userID+"postajax");

                        }

                        else    {

                            FB.login(function(response) {
                                alert('here');
                                console.log(response);

                            });
                        }
                    }

                })
             })
```

UPDATE 8.12 @felipe-brahm

Tried the following code with the same effect (pops up but is blank and closes down)

```
    $('.fb_link').click(function()  { 
    FB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', xfbml: true, cookie: true, oauth : true,          channelUrl: 'niteflymobile.com/insideny/channel.html'; },{scope: 'email'}); 
    FB.login(function(response) { 
    console.log(response); }) 
    })
```

Comment: can you post the complete code, not just the explanation?

Comment: Do you have oauth 2.0 enabled for the app - setting located in Developer app?

Comment: I do. Have tried it both ways but with no success. To be specific you mean the "OAuth Migration" selection in the Advanced tab of the Developer App for my fb application.

Answer (score 0):

The "*Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame...*" doesn't really matter. My app show's the same error on the console, but still works.

The popup is probably not opening because in most browsers a window.open event must be fired by a user initiated event, that is, a **click** a event.

**Solution**: You should ask the user to click a link that calls the login function.

Comment: Right now it is tied indirectly to the click event. I just tried tying it directly to the click event and it still launches the same way, blank window which quickly closes out and 2 XSS errors.

Comment: But it has to be called directly in the click event before the callback is finished. In your code FB.login is not called in the click event because you call it in the callback of FB.getLoginStatus which is inside the callback of FB.init... That code is async so you're not calling FB.login inside the click event.

Comment: Updated with attempt, did not work and had same effect (blank popup which closes and XSS errors)

Comment: Then please update your question because this is not what it currently says. You question says "it isn't even firing the popup with the authorization dialog" but now you are saying that the popup is in fact been opened but with a blank page... which is a totally different problem.